# Error when using an addrole command, stating "role not found"

Tags: python, exception, roles, discord.py

I want to use an addrole command that adds a role to a mentioned user, however when I type in the role it says "role x not found."

I tried using the role name, role id, I also tried using `role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)` as well, and it still won't work.

````py
@commands.command()
async def addrole(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None, *, role: discord.Role=None):
     author = ctx.message.author

     if user == None or role == None:
        await ctx.send("```Usage: ;addrole <user> <role>```")
     else:
         try:
             await user.add_roles(role)
         except Exception as e:
             print(e)
         else:
             await ctx.send(f'Added {role} to {user}')
````

Output in console, trying the role "Unapproved" (also de-capitalizes the role name, if that matters, no matter what I used as the input, and yes, this role exists in the server):

```py
Role "unapproved" not found.
```

Comment: Is the role mentionable?  If so, you can try using `@Unapproved` as your argument to the converter.

Comment: No it's not... does it have to be? Because I know some bots where it doesn't need to be mentionable

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I had an ``on_message`` event in my main .py file which turned the message string lower case and thus the role wouldn't be found.